# How to delete data in all schema without remove grant in schema

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I'm exporting a schema from Oracle 12c to 19c and importing it in a different schema. I disabled all constraints and used delete all_tables where owner 'name of schema'. Are these the steps to disable or delete any grant in schema?

First step disabled constraints, second step used this statement:

```sql
select 'delete '||table_name||' ;'
from all_tables where owner ='name of schema';
```

Comment: you can use **TRUNCATE TABLE**  for them. That's fast but quite **dangerous**, make sure you really want to get rid of all data with no turning back.

Comment: grant use in schema if this schema export and delete all data on this new schema export my question is this grant delete if yes how best practices – first step disabled constraints second step in used this statement select 'delete '||table_name||' ;' from all_tables where owner ='name of schema';

Comment: Oracle stores the whole **deleted** row in the rollback segments, they're also written to redo log files. Those operation has an adverse effect on the DB performance, and you'll have to wait for a long time. So I don't recommend you use **delete** DML, rather use **truncate** after you deciding to get rid of the whole data.

Comment: ok do the two steps you used have an effect on the grant?

Comment: _" used delete all_tables"_    You should not be deleting from ALL_TABLES or any other data dictionary table/view.  Those views are maintained by the database, and direct manipulation by you could very easily break the entire database.

Comment: The only two statements that have influence on the user's rights are `GRANT` and `REVOKE`.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you're trying to do it the *wrong* way. Which way is *right*, then? **Data Pump**. Here's how:

Source schema is `scott`; it contains tables full of data.

Connected as a privileged user (`SYS`), I'll create

- "target" schema (`mike`) which is initially empty; at the end, it'll contain all tables as `scott` does, only empty

  - you don't have to do it if target user already exists in your database
- a directory (Oracle object which points to a file system directory; it'll hold the dump file) and grant privileges to users so that they could use it: `scott`  and `mike`

---

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> SQL> create user mike identified by lion
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to mike;

Grant succeeded.
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Just to verify: `mike`'s schema is empty:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

How about `scott`? There are number of tables, mostly full of data:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
BONUS                          TABLE
CATEGORIE                      TABLE
DEPT                           TABLE
DIM_ERS_TERM_VW                TABLE
EMP                            TABLE
INGREDIENT                     TABLE
<snip>
USER_DETAILS_20211128          TABLE

21 rows selected.

SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

OK; let's export `scott`'s schema. No data, right? So use `content` parameter with `metadata_only` value, as well as `include=table` to export only tables:

```
SQL> $expdp scott/tiger directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp content=metadata_only include=table

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sub Pro 4 20:39:23 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Starting "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  scott/******** directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp content=metadata_only include=table
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Master table "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SCOTT.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\SCOTT.DMP
Job "SCOTT"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at 20:39:27


SQL>
```

Now, import into `mike`'s schema; note the `remap_schema` parameter:

```
SQL> $impdp mike/lion directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp remap_schema=scott:mike

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sub Pro 4 20:48:06 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "MIKE"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "MIKE"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  mike/******** directory=ext_dir dumpfile=scott.dmp remap_schema=scott:mike
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "MIKE"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 20:48:09


SQL>
```

What do we got?

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
BONUS                          TABLE
CATEGORIE                      TABLE
DEPT                           TABLE
DIM_ERS_TERM_VW                TABLE
EMP                            TABLE
INGREDIENT                     TABLE
<snip>
USER_DETAILS_20211128          TABLE

21 rows selected.

SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Right; tables are here, they are empty. That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: suppose the new schema contains data,
first step, I select all the constraints and disabled those constraints, then ```sql select 'delete '||table_name||' ;'
from all_tables where owner ='mike';```
select all tables and run to be deleted if you use these two steps I delete grant in my new schema or no my freind astentx  I think I answer my question : "The only two statements that have influence on the user's rights are GRANT and REVOKE."